# How do I embed Developer Tools into GeckoFx web browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools, geckofx

I'm building a developer-themed **browser in a C# .NET Windows Form Application** and want to allow users to **use Chrome or Firefox DevTools to edit/debug the current page they are viewing**. I have found several repositories online but none of them seem to be what I want.

[Example Chrome DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWZ82.png)
[Example Firefox DevTools](https://2r4s9p1yi1fa2jd7j43zph8r-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/files/2017/09/design-split-view.png)

The project uses **Geckofx60.64** to create an embedded Gecko web browser. I have already tried [debugger.html](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html) on GitHub but that didn't help me. All I need is a simple way to show website developer tools for any link.

If this is not possible, are there some other developer tools that I might be able to use with this project?

Comment: hello, I'm having the same issue as you, as I need the devtools for a project with GeckoFX 60, did you have any solution for this?

Comment: Sadly not, there seems to be very little documentation available too.

Comment: yes... little documentation and seems that no so many people is using it. For the moment I'm making my own basic inspector, as I need to inspect elements as the user is navigating. But well, it's a pity that a lots of functions it has are like hidden because there isn't much information about it.