# Elements inspector for GeckoFX 60

Tags: c#, firefox, devtools, geckofx

I'm in the need of integrate an elements inspector like the one in Chrome or Firefox into my project in C#.
I'm using GeckoFX 60 and it seems that there is nothing available. I even tried to connect the Remote debugger function of firefox with it but wasn't successful..
Is there any way to use the elements inspector with the GeckoFX, any project that simplifies it or a way to connect it with an external inspector?

Comment: You have tried this, I guess? https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issues/143/how-can-i-open-the-firefox-developer-tool It looks like the remote debug feature is broken...

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299650/how-do-i-embed-developer-tools-into-geckofx-web-browser However, no answer or upvote.